# password authentication failed for user "manager"

Tags: server, permissions, password, postgresql, nodejs

I have created a user `manager` in Ubuntu server 17. Then create a node js application behalf of this user. Then try to connect to the postgresql 10 through the following config using `postgres` user.

```
var config = {
    user: 'postgres',
    database: '<db_name>',
    password: '<password>',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5432,
    max: 10,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
};
```

But, get the following error:

> password authentication failed for user "manager"

As I am set the database user to `postgres`, why have I gotten the error on `manager` user? Also, I have granted user `manager` for all actions in the related database, and consider related posts on this error. However, my problem is not solved anymore.